Why in Rust struct only last field is allowed to have dynamically sized type
The chapter on unsized types in the first edition book says that:

Only the last field in a struct may have a dynamically sized type; the other fields must not. Enum variants must not have dynamically sized types as data.

Here I'm not able to understand reason behind such restriction. What make difference in last field?

@AndrewHenle The Rust language, however, requires that a DST field be the last field, in source code order. In other words: The rule is stricter than it technically needs to be.

@IInspectable Such a proscription prevents the inadvertent use of multiple DST fields in an obvious way.  That could be extremely useful for complex layouts.  And it could very easily be the technical method chosen to enforce the restriction against multiple DST fields for syntax reasons.  Rust is a very deeply thought out language and I'd be very hesitant to say any part of its syntax is driven merely by non-technical reasons.

@AndrewHenle I'm not debating the language rules. I'm arguing that this is a valid (and good) question. When I got here it sat at a score of -1. Thankfully this has since been corrected.

In Rust since the memory layout is unspecified the restriction of the dynamically sized type (DST) field being last is not technically necessary. That being said, the compiler has to know the size of all but one field and in memory the dynamically sized field has to be last, otherwise it couldn't statically calculate the offsets of all fields.
So requiring the DST to be last in the code is consistent with the required memory layout.
